# Elasticsearch nested query

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch, managed to set it up and import recordset from my mongodb collection using the river plugin. For a start, I want to query against the "desc" field but just can't manage to get the query .. not sure if the problem is driven by the way index was defined.. can anyone help please?

Sample recordset in elastic search looks like this

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 107209,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "shiv",
            "_type": "shiv",
            "_id": "iG1eIzN7RGO7hFfxTlnLuA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "_id": {
                  "$oid": "50901d7f485bf7bd1c000021"
               },
               "brand": "",
               "category": {
                  "$ref": "categories",
                  "$id": {
                     "$oid": "4fbd2221758cb11d14000174"
                  }
               },
               "comments": [],
               "count_comment": 0,
               "count_fav": 2,
               "count_hotness": 1.46,
               "count_rekick": 0,
               "count_share": 0,
               "country": {
                  "$ref": "countries",
                  "$id": {
                     "$oid": "4fec98f7758cb18c6e0002c9"
                  }
               },
               "currency": "pound",
               "desc": "A men&#39;s automatic watch, this Seamaster Bond model features a Co-Axial escapement and date function. Its blue dial is teamed with a stainless steel case and bracelet for a look that&#39;s sporty and refined.",
               "gender": "male",
               "ident": "omega-seamaster-diver-bond-men-s-automatic-watch---ernest-jones-1351622015",
               "img_url": "http://s7ondemand4.scene7.com/is/image/Signet/5735793?$detail$",
               "lifestyles": [
                  {
                     "$ref": "lifestyles",
                     "$id": {
                        "$oid": "508ff6ca485bf73112000060"
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "location": "United Kingdom",
               "owner": {
                  "$ref": "accounts",
                  "$id": {
                     "$oid": "50742fd8485bf74b7a00213f"
                  }
               },
               "price": 2400,
               "store": "ernestjones.co.uk",
               "tags": [
                  "ernest-jones",
                  "bond"
               ],
               "timestamp_creation": 1351622015,
               "timestamp_exp": 1356825600,
               "timestamp_update": 1351622015,
               "title": "Omega Seamaster Diver Bond men&#39;s automatic watch - Ernest Jones",
               "url": "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ernestjones.co.uk%2Fwebstore%2Fd%2F5735793%2Fomega%20seamaster%20diver%20bond%20men%27s%20automatic%20watch%2F%3Futm_source%3Dgooglebase%26utm_medium%3Dfeedmanager%26cm_mmc%3DFroogle-_-CKB-_-nurses_fobs-_-watches%26cm_mmca1%3Domega%26cm_mmca2%3Dmale%26cm_mmca3%3Dadult"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The mapping of the index "shiv" looks like

```
{
   "shiv": {
      "properties": {
         "$oid": {
            "type": "string"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks again

Comment: what queries have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are [lots of ways to query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html), have you tried a match query?

Using curl or a rest client of your choice...
http://[host]:9200/[index_name]/[doc_type]/_search

```
    {
        "query" : {
            "match" : {
                "desc" : "some value you want to find in desc"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mconlin  .. I have tried that query with valid text which is present in the index but somehow it always gives me back a zero hits. this is all i get  `{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}`

Comment: does your query work on fields that are potentially less complicated? Can you search for "gender" : "male" ? Are you searching for the right case (upper/lower). Those long descriptions with special chars could be tokenized/analyzed in odd ways. I would check your query syntax with a simple field first.

Comment: I have tried pretty much all fields with upper/lower case variants, the only field which works is the ES _id. On a separate note is there a easy way of re-indexing the data to a new index(different mapping / settings) without pushing the hefty file again? not sure if the mapping is causing the problem but don't want to spend days in pushing the file again..

Comment: there is no easy way to re-index, you can push just a few records to test it out a new index/mapping right? Can you post they query(s) you are trying?